# Python Turtle Graphics Simplification

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

just reviewing for my upcoming midterm. We were given Past midterm problems but no solutions. I am trying to grasp the knowledge best i can.

For this problem, it asks to define a function named equalSigns, pass it values t and length. So, i just need to make my program in turtle graphics, create two parellel line, simple enough i suppose. this is my code that i wrote just for it to correctly output an equal sign of x length. (then of course i would convert it to a function) My question, is there any better way to create this?

```
    import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
s=turtle.Screen()

t.forward(200)
t.penup()
t.home()
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(200) 
'''i suppose i dont have to go home and then down. 
instead just continue and go down and forward left.
but either way, is this the best approach to take?
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think there's a better way.  Most of all, I think you turned the wrong way: you need to make a second right turn to come back along the lower line.

You *could* make a routine that does a half-equals, and then all it twice to get the two lines.  Think of this as drawing a rectangle, except that the short sides are invisible.

```
# Draw long side
t.pendown()
t.forward(x)
t.penup()
t.right(90)

# Move along short side without drawing
t.forward(x/4)
t.right(90)
```

That gets you to the opposite corner of the rectangle.  Call this twice, and you're done ... and back at the starting point.

Comment: mine came out fine, just seemed a little unorthodox, thank you this i what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have your turtle think outside the shell:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as _

_.ROUND = _.BUTT

turtle.width(50)
turtle.forward(200)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.width(48)
turtle.backward(200)

turtle.done()
```

[image]

(The vertical gray bars at the two ends are artifacts of GIF conversion and not present when the program is run.)